# When drawing the texture, the center of symmetry is not in the middle？

Tags: texturing

[image]

[image]
I am drawing the texture but the center of symmetry is not in the middle?

Comment: are you sure that the origin of your object is at its center?

Comment: yes. of course.thanks

Comment: you mean yes it is at the center? Maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded. Thank you very muck~

Comment: please share the link it gives you (in the URL field)

Comment: I shared already~

Comment: you need to copy paste here  ;)  I can't see any link right now